# How to create state and assign the rows of material-ui-table with static data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am using the material-UI Table component to make a table in the UI. In the below code, I am adding static data without using state so now I want to know how to assign static data to table rows using state property of react.

I tried below code it is working fine. But now I want to display a table with static data using state property

```
import React from 'react';

import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';



function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
];

export default function SimpleTable() {

  return (
    <Paper >
      <Table >
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {rows.map(row => (
            <TableRow key={row.name}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {row.name}
              </TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="righty">{row.protein}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Comp1 state="something" />
  );
}

function Comp1(props) {
  return (
    <div>{props.div}</div>
  );
}
```

With `props` you can add as many attributes as you wish.